# Need to pair up everyone in table but I don't want anyone used more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here are the tables I have with their columns:

```
Employees: Username, Department //a list of every employee and their department
RecentHistory: Employee1, Employee2 //a list of the previous pairings
```

I need a SELECT query that pairs up everyone with another employee who is not in their department and they haven't been paired before, and I want every employee to show up only once in the returned table.
The query I have so far is this:

```
SELECT t1.Username AS Emplyee1, t2.Username AS Employee2
FROM Employees AS t1 CROSS JOIN Employees as t2
WHERE t1.Department <> t2.Department
EXCEPT
SELECT Employee1, Employee2
FROM RecentHistory
EXCEPT
SELECT Employee2, Employee1
FROM RecentHistory
```

This make it so that every possible pairing that hasn't been done yet shows up but it returns every employee multiple times and I want every employee to appear only once in the result.

If it helps this query returns the same as the `CROSS JOIN` query:

```
SELECT t1.Username, t2.Username
FROM Employees AS t1 JOIN Employees AS t2
ON (t1.Department <> t2.Department)
EXCEPT
SELECT Employee1, Employee2
FROM RecentHistory
EXCEPT
SELECT Employee2, Employee1
FROM RecentHistory
```

Comment: By the requirements you have given, there will be many different possible results of this query that you want. How did you want to handle this - did you want to randomly select one of these possibilities?

Comment: I don't care what the result is as long as everyone is listed once and only once and every pair consists of 2 employees from different Departments who haven't met before.

Comment: Seems to boil down to the [Partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). If you manage to split the set of departments into two subsets with equal total number of employees, you will be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @outTable AS TABLE (Employee1 nvarchar(20), Employee2 nvarchar(20))

DECLARE @users AS TABLE (RowId INT IDENTITY, Username nvarchar(20), Department nvarchar(20))
DECLARE @i int, @cnt int, @username nvarchar(20);

INSERT INTO @users
SELECT Username, Department FROM dbo.Employees 

SELECT @i = 1, @cnt = count(*) from @users

WHILE @i <= @cnt
BEGIN
    SELECT @username =  Username from @users where RowId = @i;

    INSERT INTO @outTable
    SELECT TOP 1 t1.Username AS Employee1, t2.Username AS Employee2 
    FROM Employees AS t1 CROSS JOIN Employees as t2
    WHERE t1.Department <> t2.Department 
    AND t1.Username = @username
    AND t1.Username not in (select Employee2 from @outTable UNION select Employee1 from @outTable)
    AND t2.Username not in (select Employee2 from @outTable UNION select Employee1 from @outTable)
    EXCEPT
    SELECT Employee1, Employee2
    FROM RecentHistory
    EXCEPT
    SELECT Employee2, Employee1
    FROM RecentHistory 

    SET @i = @i + 1

END

select * from @outTable
```